# HOWTO Fix Exception Hell in List.head if list is empty

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I need to pass head of a list to List.fold. What is the functional solution to handle `ArgumentException` for the below case if `departments` is empty.

```
let result = employees 
|> List.fold (...) (List.head departments)
```

Here, departments is a list. I did not specify the fold function here for sake of clarity.

Writing a match pattern will make my code awkard.

Comment: I honestly don't see why `let result = match departments with [] -> ? | (d::ds) -> List.fold (...) d` should be awkard - and I don't see no hell ;)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to examine the `departments` list and provide a default if it's empty. You could provide a helper function for that:

```
let headOrDefault def d =
    match d with
    | [] -> def
    | _ -> List.head d
```

which you could use like this:

```
let result = 
    employees 
    |> List.fold (...) (headOrDefault defDep departments)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `departments` can't be empty, you can use `NonEmptyList<'T>` provided by [Fsharpx.Collections](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-nonemptylist-1.html).

```
let result = employees 
|> List.fold (...) (NonEmptyList.head departments)
```

You don't need to handle ArgumentException because NonEmptyList.head never fails.